# Why response type is different?

Tags: react-native, fetch, response

I am building a simple gallery management app with React Native.
In gallery page, I called "FetchGallery" function and in there, I got some response.

> This is constructor part.

```
this.state = {
  mainGalleryData: [
    {
      bg_url: '',
      country_id: 0
    }
  ],
};
```

> That is the code for response.

```
  _onFetchGalleryBySite = (e) => {
    fetch(config.api.getGalleryInfo + '/' + e, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: this.state.myHeaders
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJSON) => {
        console.log('resJSON=>', responseJSON['gallery_list']);  // => log is in the below.
        responseJSON['gallery_list'].map(item => {
          if (item != "") {
            let obj = {}
            obj.bg_url = item.bg_url
            obj.country_id = item.country_id
            this.state.mainGalleryData.push(obj)
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('_onFetchGalleryInfoErr=>', err))
  }
```

> This is the log of fetched data

```
resJSON => [{ "bg_url": "staff_upload/bgremoval_20201008030228.png", "country_id": "3" },  
            { "bg_url":"Guest/1/image/bgremoval_20201004222851.png", "country_id": "3" }]
```

And in the render() , I used this data in the flatList

> That is the code for FlatList

```
    <FlatList
      data={mainGalleryData}
      renderItem={this.renderGallery}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
```

> This is the renderGallery.

```
  renderGallery = (item) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('itemClicked=>', item)} style={styles.overlay}>
      <Image source={newImg} style={styles.newImg} />
      {
        this.state.gallery_id == item.location_id ?
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: '700' }} numberOfLines={1}>{item.item.title}</Text>
          :
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }} numberOfLines={1}>{item.item.title}</Text>
      }
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
```

When I click one of those data, I want to get this data. But the result is different that I expect.

```
I want:  { "bg_url": "staff_upload/bgremoval_20201008030228.png", "country_id": "3" } 
result:  { "index": 2, "item": {"Guest/1/image/bgremoval_20201004222851.png", "country_id": "3"}}
```

So I had to get country_id with "item.item.country_id".

I want to get country_id with "item.country_id".

What is this <"index": 2> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before pushing response in state, please clear "mainGalleryData[]"
> because default it has 1 item in state which makes index
> inappropriate.

Do this

```
console.log('resJSON=>', responseJSON['gallery_list']);
const responseData = responseJSON['gallery_list'];
const data = this.state.mainGalleryData.concat(responseData); <-- add this line -->
this.state({ mainGalleryData: data });
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear response. Then actually I need the initial value of mainGalleryData[] as the first item of that array. Is there any other way to fix this issue keeping the initial value of array?

Comment: Why you need to keep the initial array item while it's default values are empty which effects on the result when you click the item and it gives you the next item.

Comment: The data which comes from server is "1,2,3,4,5, ..." type. But I need "0,1,2,3,4,5,..." this type. That's why I set the initial value as empty.  Then except this way, is there any another good way? How to set the first value of array empty?

Comment: I have updated my answer, in that way you can have data line 0,1,2...5